# Should CSLA be used with a dependency injection framework?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, spring.net, csla

My development team is evaluating the various frameworks available for .NET to simplify our programming, one of which is CSLA.  I have to admit to being a bit confused as to whether or not CSLA would benefit from being used in conjunction with a dependency injection framework, such as Spring.net or Windsor.  If we combined one of those two DI frameworks with, say, the Entity Framework to handle ORM duties, does that negate the need or benefit of using CSLA altogether?

I have various levels of understanding of all these frameworks, and I'm trying to get a big picture of what will best benefit our enterprise architecture and object design.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSLA is a framework for creating business entities, so has separate concerns than an IoC container or ORM. In a enterprise application you should consider the benefits of all three.

In particular, you should consider CSLA if you want data binding built in to your models, dirty checking, N-level undo, validation and business rules, as well as the data portal implementation which allows easy configuration for n-tier deployments.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how data-binding would be useful in an object model?  Wouldn't it be best to separate the binding from the actual object being modeled?  As for my team's particular situation, we're aiming for a mostly SOA architecture, and the use of CSLA as I envisioned it would be on the service side, not the client side where I would expect the data-binding to reside.  Of course, I very well may be overlooking a big aspect and benefit of CSLA, not to mention misunderstanding your use of data-binding!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Data binding is particularly useful for building WPF/Silverlight/Windows Phone 7 applications where the MVVM design pattern is prevalent, and view updates are performed through data binding, so that changes in the view affect the model, and changes in the model affect the view. Rocky's CSLA properties support data binding so you don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your models. This isn't the biggest benefit of CSLA, but it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Yes.

**Long answer:** It requires a bit of grunt work and some experimentation to setup, but it can be done without fundamentally breaking CSLA. I put together a working prototype using StructureMap and the repository pattern and used [the BuildUp method of Setter Injection](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm) to inject within CSLA. I used a method similar to the one found [here](http://jonnybekkum.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/cslacontrib-mef-and-repository-pattern-with-csla4/) to ensure that my business objects are re-injected when the objects are serialized.

I also use the registry base class of StructureMap to separate my configuration into presentation, CSLA client, CSLA server, and CSLA global settings. This way I can use the linked file feature of Visual Studio to include the CSLA server and CSLA global configuration files within the server-side Data Portal and the configuration will always be the same in both places. This was to ensure I can still change the Data Portal configuration settings in CSLA from 2 tier to 3 tier without breaking anything.

Anyway, I am still weighing the potential benefits with the drawbacks to using DI, but so far I am leaning in the direction of using it because testing will be much easier although I am skeptical of trying to use any of the advanced features of DI such as interception. I recommend reading the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) by Mark Seemann to understand the right and wrong way to use DI because there is a lot of misinformation on the Internet.